# Creating Truly Empty Types in Python

Tags: python, types, dictionary

On a regular basis, I want to create completely empty objects in Python. Basically, I want to have a dict where the keys are attributes. In Python 2.x, I can create an old-style type like this:

```
class Empty: pass
```

This will create a type that only has two attributes (`__doc__` and `__module__`). In Python 3.x, everything is a new-style class, so I get 18 attributes.

In my current situation, I have a class that allows you to specify types that need monkey patched within a unit test. When the patches are applied, I am creating a type with attributes with the names of each mocked-out type. This is pretty much what my current implementation is doing:

```
class EmptyType: pass
...
mocks = EmptyType()
for mock_name, mock in patches:
    setattr(mocks, mock_name, mock)
```

My concern is that should someone be mocking a private member, they might run into naming collisions with the names in the `EmptyType` object. That's why I'd like to keep as few attributes in the `EmptyType` as possible. And it is way easier to say `mocks.find_users` than it is to say `mocks["find_users"]`, especially when I know the name has to be a valid identifier.

Right now, I have provided the ability to give mocks different names, other than what would otherwise be the default. Still, it would be nice to avoid confusing errors in the first place. It is very easy to create *almost* empty types in JavaScript and I was hoping there was something similar in Python, since I keep finding good uses for them.

Comment: I don't really know why, but this pattern seems a little alien for Python. Monkey-patching is often frowned upon in Python circles, duck-typing and EAFP are encouraged.

Comment: take a look at [mock](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/unittest.mock)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What about creating your own custom container?

```
class Empty(object):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        object.__setattr__(self, '_obj', kwargs)

    def __getattribute__(self, name):
        obj = object.__getattribute__(self, '_obj')
        try:
            return obj[name]
        except KeyError:
            cls_name = object.__getattribute__(self, '__class__').__name__
            raise AttributeError(
                "'%(cls_name)s' object has no attribute '%(name)s'" % locals())

    def __setattr__(self, name, val):
        obj = object.__getattribute__(self, '_obj')
        obj[name] = val

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return getattr(self, key)

    def __setitem__(self, key, val):
        return setattr(self, key, val)
```

Usage:

```
e = Empty(initial='optional-value')
e.initial
# 'optional-value'
e.val = 'foo'
e.val
# 'foo'
e.bad
# AttributeError: 'Empty' object has no attribute 'bad'
setattr(e, 'user', 'jdi')
e.user
# 'jdi'
e['user']
# 'jdi'

# note that you dont even see anything when you dir()
dir(e)
# []

# and trying to access _obj is protected
e._obj
#AttributeError: 'Empty' object has no attribute '_obj'

# But you could even set your own _obj attribute
e._obj = 1
e._obj
# 1
```

It will store everything under a `_obj` dictionary so you  basically get a clean space that doesn't conflict with the actual instance attributes.

Comment: +1 for using `__getattribute__` instead of the more common `__getattr__`.  ( I had to look up the difference to convince myself that `__getattribute__` was really what you wanted ... )

Comment: @mgilson: Thanks! Ya I still have to remind myself about the special builtins. For anyone reading that comment, I used `__getattribute__` to make sure it always handles the accessing of attributes and redirects them to the private dictionary, regardless of whether they might already exist on that Empty class.

Comment: One other comment -- I can't think of any reason to have the last line in `__getattribute__` (`return object.__getattribute__(self, name)` ).  Is that just to raise the `AttributeError` if the attribute doesn't exist?  If so, why not raise it more directly (explicitly) using a `try/except` catching the `KeyError` and re-raising it as an `AttributeError`?

Comment: @mgilson: My only reason for doing that was to let the `object` take care of the standard `AttributeError` string formatting and whatnot. I would just be reproducing the similar error. I could have done that if I wanted a custom message though. It just didn't seem all that critical to handle it explicitly in this case.

Comment: I think this is my last comment.  Instead of using `'_obj'` as the name of the single attribute, you could use `'100'` or something else which isn't a valid identifier.  Then you eliminate the namespace clash problem entirely (since `a.100` isn't valid syntax).

Comment: @mgilson: LOL! That comment just proved a reason to explicitly raise the AttributeError instead of allowing the super method to access `_obj`. Good job. Just updated it.

Comment: I actually used a dumbed down version of this code in my project. I made the type somewhat immutable by forcing everything to be passed to the __init__ as kwargs. I also added a "create=False" parameter to __init__ that specifies whether unconfigured attributes cause an AttributeError or create a new mock automatically. I named the two true attributes "#fields" and "#create".

Comment: Awesome. Ya you can do a lot with those special methods to lock up the instance how you want.